# How to combine types in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Here I'm trying to create a function that sets dimensions.

the dims could either be an object array or just a number.

```
dimensions(
    dims: { width: number; height: number } | Array<number> | number,
  ) {

console.log(dims.width)

}
```

But if I access dims.width I'm getting type error width doesnot exists on property dims with type   `{ width: number; height: number } | Array<number> | number`

How can I solve this?

Easy way is to do like this `dims['width']`. Is there any alternative?

Comment: That error is **correct**. You've said `dims` could be one of three types, only one of which would have a `width` property, so accessing that property without checking is unsafe. Look at e.g. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types for how to handle it in a type-safe way.

Comment: @jonrsharpe you beat me with the link :D

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is absolutely right: if `dims` is (say) a number, `dims.width` would yield `undefined`. The compiler doesn't allow that. You need to narrow the type:

```
function normalizeDims(
  dims: { width: number; height: number } | Array<number> | number
  ): { width: number; height: number } {
  if (typeof dims === 'number') {
    // in this block the TS compiler knows dims is a number:
    return { width: dims, height: dims };
  }
  if (Array.isArray(dims)) {
    // here the TS compiler knows dims is an Array<number>
    if (dims.length !== 2) throw Error();
    return { width: dims[0], height: dims[1] };
  }
  // here the compiler has narrowed down the type of dims to object
  return dims;
}

function dimensions(
    dims: { width: number; height: number } | Array<number> | number,
  ) {
  const normalized = normalizeDims(dims);
  console.log(normalized.width)
}
```

Look [in the TS docs](http://at%20https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types). They have lots of examples that cover exactly this case and many more. And, it's just one (longish) page.

Comment: Is there a way for me to deconstruct ```const [width, height] = dims  ``` or ```const {width, height} = dims  ```? Cause when I try it is throwing error.

Comment: Both syntaxes are acceptable, in different cases: the first deconstructs an array, the second an object. So the same kind of type checks in the answer above is needed: you can deconstruct only _after_ the compiler has ensured the actual type of dims.